# g++ failed to resolve non-inlined function in a static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, static-linking

I'm writing a c++ program that is dependent on a c/c++ 3rd-party library. I compiled the 3rd-party library as a static library both on windows and linux. My code works correctly on linux, but on windows there's linking error indicating that my code fails to resolve the symbols in the 3rd-party library.

After some debugging, I found that the unresolved references are non-inline functions in that library and inline functions can be resolved (I've tested). Originally I thought it's the incompatibility between gcc and msvc, because I compiled the .lib files using msvc while attempted to compile my code with g++ through mingw. I recompiled the library with g++ on windows and there's the same problem.

Any idea what might be the solution?

=========Edit===============

Just to clarify, the 3rd-party library is not templated.

Comment: Does it say it failed to resolve symbols in the 3rd party library or because the symbols in the 3rd party library need some function that has not been linked in?

Comment: It says that it failed to resolve symbols in the 3rd party library. I did a simple test: define one class object with the class type in the  library, and the error is that the constructor of the class is unresolved.@cup

Comment: Just a long shot: have you tried adding the library twice on the link line?  Sometimes, because of circular dependency, the library needs to be added multiple times.

Comment: I tried that although I'm pretty sure there's no circular dependency, same error. Weird that inline functions are resolved correctly.

Comment: Inline functions are resolved because the sources are compiled from the header.  Are you sure it is picking up your libraries?  Check your -L paths.

Comment: does your static lib (compiled by g++) is .a or .lib? can it be you continue to take the old one?

Comment: I've found the problem and posted the answer. My lib files are *.lib are on windows and lib*.a on windows. As you expected, g++ didn't link to the correct lib files. It tried to link to lib*.a first which was generated on linux. So, here's the problem.@SHR

Comment: My -L paths are correct. The reason is that g++ tries to link to the lib*.a files generated on linux prior to *.lib files generated on windows, which I put in the same directoy.Now it's correct as I put them in separate directories.@cup

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted if the problem is solved.

Comment: I will when I'm allowed to. I can only accept my own answer 2 days after the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I put both the lib*.a (generated on linux) and *.lib (generated on windows) of the 3rd-party library in the same directory, because I want this code to be cross-platform. While compiling my code in windows with g++, it seems link to the lib*.a files in priority which leads to "unresolved symbols" error. I deleted the lib*.a files and g++ now link to the *.lib file, and works correctly.